# PHP session_start revives previous session variables

Tags: php

I've got a problem with session_start() function.

This is the first time I met this problem, I have a few session variables. When I open logout.php file, session is destoryed. But then, when I call session_start(), all the previous session variables "revive".

logout.php

```php
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
```

Even when I delete all the $_SESSION data manually like:

```php
$_SESSION = array();
```

those variables are still there after calling session_start();

I have no idea why does session_start work like that.

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: You also call `session_start` before `session_destroy`???  You can't destroy a session that isn't started.  Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php depends on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Of course, session is initialized. The problem appears when I want to destroy current session.

Comment: Just make variables some default value on logout. You can add maybe booleand `value isLogged`

Comment: I have some important data in session variables. I must destroy session on logout. But why session_start() restores all the previous session variables?